# How can I determine the number of worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way, with VBA, to determine the number of worksheets in a workbook and perform calculations on a predefined range of cells in those worksheets?

Worksheets are regularly added to the workbook and we need to calculate the sum of a specific range of cells.

I googled it but did not find any solution.

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count`

Answer (score 5):

## Loop Through Worksheets With Exceptions List

### New Post (03/30/2021)

> - Let's say I've learned a thing or two since this answer was posted. Since it was one of my best-received ones, I decided to add an improvement (correction) addressing the
>   following issues:
>
>   - introducing a range to make the solution more OP(user)-friendly: *... we need to calculate the sum of a specific range of cells...*,
>   - qualifying the worksheets by creating a reference to the workbook: `Dim wb...` and `wb.Worksheets` vs `Worksheets`,
>   - getting rid of Hungarian notation: `Exceptions` vs `vntExceptions`,
>   - declaring the array as a string: `() As String` vs `As Variant`,
>   - and getting rid of the inner loop by using `Application.Match` vs `For j = 0... Next j`.
> - I'll be leaving the old post since it is working (inferiorly) and is educational in handling `For` loops, using `Exit For`, and checking
>   the counter if it is greater than the upper limit of the array to
>   determine if a value has been found in the array.

- Performs operations in the '**Code in here**' section on all worksheets in the workbook containing this code, except the ones in the `Exception List`.

**At Least One Exception**

```
Option Explicit

Sub loopThroughWorksheets()
        
    Const ExceptionsList As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2"
    Const RangeAddress As String = "A1:E5"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim Exceptions() As String: Exceptions = Split(ExceptionsList, ",")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            ' Code in here e.g.
            Debug.Print ws.Name, Application.Sum(ws.Range(RangeAddress))
        
        End If
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

If you'll allow the `Exceptions List` to be empty (`""`) use the following code:

**No Exceptions Is Allowed**

```
Sub loopThroughWorksheets()
        
    Const ExceptionsList As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2"
    Const RangeAddress As String = "A1:E5"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim Exceptions() As String: Exceptions = Split(ExceptionsList, ",")
    
    Dim wsNames() As String: ReDim wsNames(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    
    If UBound(Exceptions) = -1 Then ' no exception: 'ExceptionList = ""'
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            n = n + 1
            wsNames(n) = ws.Name
        Next ws
    Else
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
                n = n + 1
                wsNames(n) = ws.Name
            End If
        Next ws
        ReDim Preserve wsNames(1 To n)
    End If
    
    For n = 1 To n
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsNames(n))
      ' Code in here e.g.
        Debug.Print ws.Name, Application.Sum(ws.Range(RangeAddress))
    
    Next n
    
End Sub
```

### Old Post (12/30/2018)

> - Performs operations in the '**Code in here**' section on all    worksheets except the ones in the Exception Comma-Separated List.
> - The difference between the two versions is that the first version    uses the object control variable `ws`, but the second version doesn't need it, but uses the control variable `i` and the `.Count` property of the `Worksheets` collection.
> - If you don't have any exceptions i.e. you want to perform operations on all worksheets, then just leave `cExceptions` as **""**.

**The For Each Next Approach**

```
Sub WorksheetsForEach()

  ' Exceptions Comma-Separated List
  Const cExceptions As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2"
  
  Dim ws As Worksheet           ' Current Worksheet
  Dim vntExceptions As Variant  ' Exceptions Array
  Dim j As Integer              ' Exceptions Counter
    
  vntExceptions = Split(cExceptions, ",")
  
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
      For j = 0 To UBound(vntExceptions)
        If .Name = vntExceptions(j) Then
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      If j > UBound(vntExceptions) Then
      ' Code in here e.g.
        Debug.Print .Name
      
      End If
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

**The For Next Approach**

```
Sub WorksheetsForNext()

  ' Exceptions Comma-Separated List
  Const cExceptions As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2"
  
  Dim vntExceptions As Variant  ' Exceptions Array
  Dim i As Integer              ' Worksheets Counter
  Dim j As Integer              ' Exceptions Counter
    
  vntExceptions = Split(cExceptions, ",")
  
  For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    With Worksheets(i)
      For j = 0 To UBound(vntExceptions)
        If .Name = vntExceptions(j) Then
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      If j > UBound(vntExceptions) Then
      ' Code in here e.g.
        Debug.Print .Name
      
      End If
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```